# How do you create a new user to login with for Amazon Ubuntu EC2?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I really don't like using my root user with no password to use for logging in an Amazon EC2 ubuntu instance.  I would like to login without the certificate if possible.  I had seen a tutorial where they said you can, but they didn't explain how to do it.

```
adduser newuser
gpasswd -a user sudo
```

That's as far as I got.  Creating a `newuser` username and giving them `sudo` priviledges.  I know there has to be something I am missing for linking this to a login.

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking for requires console access, and there is no console access provided by Amazon.

Your *gpasswd* line would also need to change to `gpasswd -a newuser sudo` since you created the new user using the user id *newuser*.

Next, you need to create a `.ssh/authorized_keys` file for the *newuser* inside of which would be the public key of the certificate (assuming by *certificate* you meant the *.pem* file).

Then you ought to be able to ssh newuser@*your_public_ec2_dns*.

Comment: I was looking for commands to help me understand it more from theory to practice. :)

Comment: In theory you could edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config and change `PasswordAuthentication yes` to allow password authentication. In theory with this, it's possible that keyboard loggers could be used to get your password, but if you only use ssh keys, then they'd have to also have your private key. This is one reason why password authentication is disabled by default.